# Adding specific system.xml to store config in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add fields for configuration to stores in my Magento 2 application with my module that i am building.

The problem is I cant find any documentation on adding it to store. I can only find that it can be added to global configuration and that is not the place i want to have it.

So i want to find a way to make this happen this is my normal configuration for my general config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Koppelingen</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="exact" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Exact Online</label>
            <tab>mageplaza</tab>
            <resource>Mageplaza_HelloWorld::hello_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="exact" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Id Of Exact</label>
                    <comment>Exact Online Id</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Secret Of Exact</label>
                    <comment>Exact Online Secret</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="base_url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Base Url</label>
                    <comment>Base Url For Callback</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="project" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Project</label>
                    <comment>The place to fill in your project for the store</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

This updated `system.xml` file is what you have to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Koppelingen</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="exact" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Exact Online</label>
        <tab>mageplaza</tab>
        <resource>Mageplaza_HelloWorld::hello_configuration</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="exact" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Id Of Exact</label>
                <comment>Exact Online Id</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Secret Of Exact</label>
                <comment>Exact Online Secret</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="base_url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Base Url</label>
                <comment>Base Url For Callback</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="project" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Project</label>
                <comment>The place to fill in your project for the store</comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

It will enable configuration on all levels: Global, Website and Store.

Answer (score 0):

change `showInStore="0"` to `showInStore="1"` on `field` and `group` level for it to display on store scope.

From the XML-schema we can see that you define with integer 1/0 the visibility level of your configuration setting. In your case the `section` attribute `showInDefault`,`showInWebsite` and `showInStore` is the only one set to 1, so section will display on store scope but not the individual field configuration settings.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Config/etc/system.xsd#L61